# Why code returns output plus undefined

Tags: javascript

Why code returns output + `undefined`?

A function, where argument `h` is equal `680131659347`. Output is `leepadgdenifednu`. It's leepadg + denifednu (undefined).

```
var f = function (h) {
  var letters, result, i;

  i = 7;
  letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

  while (i) {
    result += letters[parseInt(h % 37)];
    h = h / 37;
    i--;
  }
  return result.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

Comment: I get `leepadgdenifednu`, so it works fine, I suppose

Comment: Where exactly are you getting undefined? Please post a complete example

Comment: @AmitJoki `leepadgdenifednu` it's `leepadg` + `denifednu` (undefined)

Comment: Give `result` an initial value to concatenate onto -- `var letters, result = '', i;`.

Comment: What is the while condition?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thank you so much! Why you didn't a answer? :-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to initialize the value of result, when you way `var result`, `result` will have a value of `undefined` then when you use it in a string concatenation the value will be `undefined+<concatenated value>`

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).prependTo($log)
  }
})();

var f = function(h) {
  var letters, result = '',
    i;

  i = 7;
  letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

  while (i) {
    result += letters[parseInt(h % 37)];
    h = h / 37;
    i--;
  }
  return result.split("").reverse().join("");
};

log(f(680131659347))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were Not Initialize the **Result**   and You are Try to **Concate** the value to result

```
 var f = function (h) {
      var letters, result, i;
    result=//Initialize Result
      i = 7;
      letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

      while (i) {
        result += letters[parseInt(h % 37)]; 
        h = h / 37;
        i--;
      }
      return result.split("").reverse().join("");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 var f = function (h) {
      var letters, result, i;

      i = 7;
      letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
result="";// initailize result
      while (i) {
        result += letters[parseInt(h % 37)];
        h = h / 37;
        i--;
      }
      return result.split("").reverse().join("");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

result is not initialized as string so very first time of concatenation its generate an error like undefined then its ok , so initialize  the result variable as result=''

```
var f = function (h) {
  var letters, result='', i;

  i = 7;
  letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

  while (i) {
    result += letters[parseInt(h % 37)];
    h = h / 37;
    i--;
  }
  return result.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```